# Limit points of open and closed sets in Real Numbers .

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, limits, metric-spaces

***Q1)***  Let ***A*** be an open set in real line **R**. (here we are using the standard metric).

Prove or disprove that every point of ***A*** is a limit point.

***Q2)*** Similarly, ***B*** be a closed set in **R**  , with standard metric.

Prove or disprove that every point of ***B*** is a limit point.

*I gave an answer as follows;*

Since ***A*** is an open set in **R**, for each element in the set i can find an open ball which contains some different elements of *A* . So all element are should be limit points.*

*For second question , i am thinking as same as above.*

*I just want to get some help, if i have any mistake. Thanks*

Comment: Reconsider for closed sets. Please formulate exactly how you see the argument for closed sets.

Answer (score 0):

You have answered Q1 youself. For Q2 consider the set $\{1,2\}$. Then $1$ is not a limit point of $\{1,2\}$. So the statement in Q2 is false.

Answer (score 0):

You are right about ***Q1***, but a counterexample to ***Q2*** is the set with only one element $S=\{a\}$ ($a$ is the only element of $S$ and $a$ isn't a limit point of $S$).